# What kind of data format is this

Tags: dataformat

I have a 3rd party application which stored the data in the below format, I haven't seen any such format before

A<1,?,'clientID'=?,'displayType'='show','firstName'='First','id'=1234567,'info'=A<1,?,'acceptUser'=48141315,'nodeID'=1234567,'shareUser'=63490234>,'lastName'='Last','shareOwner'=63490234,'subtype'='shareaccepted','toUser'=48141315,'type'='notification','userID'=48141315,'username'='lastFirst'>

Comment: Don't they provide a doc?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a custom format. They should be telling you what format it is, you shouldn't have to guess, it should be documented somewhere.

So first thing you should do is ask them.

Now, if you indent it, it looks pretty straightforward. `A<...>` seems to define an object.

```
A<
    1,
    ?,
    'clientID'=?,
    'displayType'='show',
    'firstName'='First',
    'id'=1234567,
    'info'=A<
        1,
        ?,
        'acceptUser'=48141315,
        'nodeID'=1234567,
        'shareUser'=63490234
    >,
    'lastName'='Last',
    'shareOwner'=63490234,
    'subtype'='shareaccepted',
    'toUser'=48141315,
    'type'='notification',
    'userID'=48141315,
    'username'='lastFirst'
>
```

Unless this is a known format, I am afraid you will have to parse it yourself.

An other way could be to manually translate it to Json (with a custom class of your own) and then use `Gson` or `Jackson` to parse it to POJOs.

A JSON equivalent would be

```
{
    "v1": 1,
    "v2": "?",
    "clientID": "?",
    "displayType": "show",
    "firstName": "First",
    "id": 1234567,
    "info":  {
        "v1": 1,
        "v2": "?",
        "acceptUser": 48141315,
        "nodeID": 1234567,
        "shareUser": 63490234
    },
    "lastName": "Last",
    "shareOwner": 63490234,
    "subtype": "shareaccepted",
    "toUser": 48141315,
    "type": "notification",
    "userID": 48141315,
    "username": "lastFirst"
}
```

Comment: thanks, i have already decode it to parse it. Just curious to know the format.